# Count of times a value in one df is exceeded in a second df subject to other conditions

Tags: r

I have a history of transactions in a dataframe.  Each transaction has three attributes: year, size and color.

```
Transactions <- data.frame(Size=c("S","S","S","S","L","L","S","L"),                     
                       Color=c("R","R","R","B","R","B","B","R"),
                       Year=c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2))
 Size Color Year  
 S     R     1   
 S     R     1   
 S     R     2   
 S     B     1   
 L     R     1   
 L     B     1   
 S     B     2   
 L     R     2
```

So the first, second and third transactions are: SR1, SR1, and SR2.  That's three SR transactions.  Two in year 1 and one in year 2.

I'd like report in the form of a df that summarizes, for each combination of color and size, the number of times the year is matched, or exceeded.  So, for the data above a correct *final report* is shown below.

```
Size Color Year Count 
 S     R     1   3 (from obs 1,2,3 because there are 3 SRs Yr 1 or later)
 S     R     2   1 (from row 3 of transaction b/c just one SR2)
 S     B     1   2
 S     B     2   1
 L     R     1   2
 L     R     2   1
 L     B     1   1
 L     B     2   0 (Because  LB2  doesn't appear in transactions.
```

The sequence of the rows in the report doesn't come from the transaction frame.  It's a complete permutation of all of the levels of size, color, and Year.  In my real problem, I have a df with the structure of the first three cols in the report, so I'd like to be able to just append last col to it.  This df without the final col would be:

```
Report <- data.frame(Size= c("S","S","S","S","L","L","L","L"),
                 Color=c("R","R","B","B","R","R","B","B"),
                 Year= c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
                 )
```

I would like to append the final col, but if there's a way to generate it directly from the transactions, that's fine, too.  But since it's possible that some report combinations don't appear in the transactions I don't think that's feasible.

Comment: Your example doesn't match the output you've provided. And your description doesn't match the desired output, e.i., row 6 has different size from rows 1 & 2, hence it's not clear why they are related in your desired output

Comment: I have no clue what you want

Comment: I've edited the post by rearranging the transaction list, adding the listing of transactions and annotating the report.  I hope that makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
Transactions <- data.frame(Size=c("S","S","S","S","L","L","S","L"),                     
                           Color=c("R","R","R","B","R","B","B","R"),
                           Year=c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2))
library("data.table")
setDT(Transactions)
allYears <- Transactions[, unique(Year)]
Transactions[, .(Year=allYears, count=sapply(allYears, function(y) sum(Year>=y))), by=.(Size, Color)]
# > Transactions[, .(Year=allYears, count=sapply(allYears, function(y) sum(Year>=y))), by=.(Size, Color)]
#    Size Color Year count
# 1:    S     R    1     3
# 2:    S     R    2     1
# 3:    S     B    1     2
# 4:    S     B    2     1
# 5:    L     R    1     2
# 6:    L     R    2     1
# 7:    L     B    1     1
# 8:    L     B    2     0
```